# Run a command in all subfolders

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following command I'd like to run in all subfolders:

```
for f in *.mp4; do
ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "tmp_${f}" && mv "tmp_${f}" "${f}"
done
```

Folder structure:
In the base folder 2019 I want to execute in all subfolders the command. There is a folder for every month, i.e. for january "/home/okr/test/2019/01/"

Comment: What subfolders?

Comment: Do you mean _recursively_ ?

Comment: If recursively means in all subfolders: yes

Answer (score 0):

Recursively:

```
shopt -s globstar

for f in **/*.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "${f}.tmp" && mv "${f}.tmp" "${f}"
done
```

Comment: The `$f` will contain the full (relative) path to the MP4 file. So, you should append the `.tmp` at the end rather than trying to prepend it (as in `"$f.tmp"` rather than `"tmp_$f"`) - this is "leading-up path safe".

Comment: Then ffmpeg sais:

"FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place."

Comment: @Schöbi that's why you really should show us the directory structure you are working on so we don't need to guess what you want.

Comment: @terdon in the base folder 2019 I want to execute in all subfolders the command there is a folder for every month, i.e. for january "/home/okr/test/2019/01/"

Comment: @Schöbi please add all relevant information to your question not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is either to `cd` into each sub folder and run the command, which you can do like this:

```
for dir in */; do
 ( 
  cd "$dir"
  for f in ./*.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "tmp_${f}" && mv "tmp_${f}" "${f}"
  done
 )
done
```

(The parentheses open a subshell which lets you `cd` in the subshell without affecting your location in the parent shell)/

Or you want to simply find all mp4 files recursively and run the command on them which you can do like this:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.mp4; do
  ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "${f}.tmp" && mv "${f}.tmp" "${f}"
 done
```

The globstar option gives you `**` which from (`man bash`):

> If  set,  the  pattern  `**` used in a pathname expansion context will
> match all files and zero or more  directories and subdirectories.   If
> the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories
> match.

Comment: `shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**.mp4; do
  ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "${f}.tmp" && mv "${f}.tmp" "${f}"
 done`

gives: "./**.mp4: No such file or directory"

Comment: Sorry, @Schöbi, I had a bug. That should have been `for f in **/*.mp4`, please see updated answer.

Comment: I got it to work:

`for f in **/*.mp4; do     ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "${f}.tmp.mp4" && mv "${f}.tmp.mp4" "${f}.mp4"; done`

ffmpeg can't converte .tmp, the ending must be .mp4

Edit: There is still a bug: the output file has the ending mp4.mp4 and the original file is not deleted.

Comment: @Schöbi this is really hard for us to test without a specific example. If you've found the solution, please edit it into one of the answers or post your own. Otherwise, show us something that we can use to reproduce your setup and test our answers properly. As for the double extension, use `mv "${f}.tmp.mp4" "${f}";`

Answer (score 0):

The following command will search recursively through all subfolders of the current directory for files with the `.mp4` extension (`-name "*.mp4"`) and execute the `ffmpeg` command on each file using the `-exec` option.

```
for f in *.mp4; do
  ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "tmp_${f}" && 
    mv "tmp_${f}" "${f}"
done
```

Comment: Did you mean to post a `find` command? This is just the exact same command from the question.

Comment: This gives me an error:

./**.mp4: No such file or directory

Comment: @Schöbi this answer doesn't mention `**` anywhere. But if you want to use `**`, you need to enable it with `shopt -s globstar` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in **/*.mp4; do     
ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac "${f}.tmp.mp4" && mv "${f}.tmp.mp4" "${f}"; 
done
```

Thanks you all for supporting!